# ListWidget: How to click a List Item programmatically

Tags: python, pyqt, selection, qlistwidget

After a QtGui.QListWidget was populated with the list items ( QtGui.QListWidgetItem )  I would like to select a very first list item (just the way it happens when a user clicks on list item with left-click mouse). 
What command or method would get me there?

#### EDITED

MyListWidget.**setCurrentRow(0)** method makes/sets a first list_item current. But it doesn't trigger any functions a list_item could be connected to.... no signal get emitted...

Comment: Can't you emit it yourself then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setCurrentRow](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentRow-prop):

```
    self.list.setCurrentRow(0)
```